# How to write a query to control a datasheet subform's combobox based on a linked table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I would like my users to select from a pre-defined **project list** combobox in a subform. The easy way would be to use lookup fields, but I've been told to avoid those like poison. To provide context, I have two linked tables, one for User Entry, and one that stores projects.

**User Entry Table**

```
PK   ProjectFK   Projected Hours   Actual Hours
1       1              15               13
2       3              12               14
3       4              13               13
```

**Project List Table**

```
PK   ProjectName
1    Caterpillar
2    Omaha
3    Dilly
4    Holdout
```

On a separate main form, the **User Entry Table** serves as a datasheet subform where users select which projects they're working on, and how many hours they spend on them. Rather than having users select the project by foreign key, I was hoping the users could select the project by **Project Name** located in the linked table.

I'm having trouble experimenting/visualizing this process. Does it involve a query, and if so, how should I go about it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have figured it out -  I created a query based off the **Project List Table**, incorporating every field. Afterward in my **User Entry Subform**, I created a combobox control with the **User Entry's** foreign key as its control source, and the query as its row source. Linking the correct control source was what was throwing me off.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is indeed the way to do it: I think you were initially confusing your actual data (where you **don't** want to use a lookup field) with the presentation/UI (which, as you note, you can use a combobox to force valid selections).

Comment: Many Access developers avoid lookup fields "like poison", but I have never understood, why. Lookup fields don't affect table data, but they make Access display comboboxes in datasheet of the tables or queries (like an advanced format setting). What I avoid "like poison" is providing datasheets of tables or queries to my users. To me, lookup fields are a development feature that lets me define the combobox settings long before I create a form to display that field. Doing so, my "development tool Access" will create a combobox with my pre-defined settings whenever I add that field to a form.

Comment: @Wolfgang, re:lookup fields - I think it's mainly because they actually confuse beginners, as they hide the underlying data. When they then try a more complicated query or form containing one, often they can't grasp that the data stored is in another partially hidden table. Also they don't upscale to other DBMS very well.

Comment: @Minty: I completely agree that lookup fields can be confusing for beginners and also don't upscale very well (same with any other display feature like "Description", "Caption" or "Format"). But those people that preach not to use lookup fields really can't be referred to as *beginners*. :-)

Comment: While I was searching on StackOverflow for an answer to my question, users would always post this in response to using lookup fields: http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm